# vue jwt token storage

Tags: security, vue.js, jwt

I am following vue course on udemy and have looked at several online resources and they all seem to have a process where i send username and password to my api and it returns my jwt access token. Then the token is stored in state (using vuex) and to support page refreshes(and keeping user logged in) it also saves jwt token to local storage.

As i am not using cookies my understanding is that i dont have to worry about csrf.

OWASP advises against storing tokens in local storage (mainly i believe due the xss vunerabilities that exist).
authO website (https://auth0.com/docs/security/store-tokens) says i should store in memory(eg like im doing with vuex).

How can i follow the advice of not using local storage and also ensure that if user refreshes page that they are still logged in (without cookies) or is this not going to be possible.

Comment: Isn't the Amplify library for AWS Cognito storing the JWT token in the localStorage too? I think it does. And Cognito is PCI-DSS certified solution. So I see no problems with using localStorage for JWT token.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm not a security expert. If your company has a security officer or so you might want to discuss the matter there as well.

OWASP states you should not store sensitive information in localStorage (or WebSQL/IndexDb). But I think you should balance your options. If it is OK that the user needs to login every time because of some really sensitive information, you might get away with sessionStorage or keep the token in memory. Otherwise, just go with localStorage. As an example: Hit F12 and look at what SO is using: LocalStorage.

There's also a nice answer on the matter at [Security StackExchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/175783/is-the-owasp-recommendation-regarding-localstorage-still-valid)